# Debugging PyCharm?

Tags: ide, pycharm, breakpoints, step-into

Could someone guide me on debugging PyCharm in step into, over, out or put in a breakpoints. I am using 2017.1 version.

These options are greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Debug or press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, then they will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the breaking points in your code first. After that, all of them will be enabled.